# Регулярное выражение по поиску ссылок

Tags: php

Почему слово Anet программа воспринимает как часть домена .net? Хотя если прописать просто net то, всё будет хорошо. Так же и с другими зонами.

```
$string = "Anet";

if (!preg_match ("/http|https|www|.ru|.com|.net|.info|.org/i", $string)) {

   echo "Нет ссылки";

} else { 

   echo "Есть ссылка";

}
```

Comment: Потому что в регулярных выражениях точка является обозначением *любого* символа — в том числе символа A.

Comment: @andreymal А как же сделать что бы точки были именно точками?

Comment: Экранировать обратным слэшем

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Почему слово Anet программа воспринимает как часть домена .net?*

Потому что символ точки в регулярных выражениях соответствует **почти любому символу**. Исключение составляют символы перевода на новую строку, но если указан модификатор `s` - точка будет соответствовать **любым символам**. Как было сказано в комментарии, для поиска символа точки достаточно её экранировать:

```
$string = "Anet";

if (! preg_match('~https?|www|\.(?:ru|com|net|info|org)~i', $string)) {
    echo "Нет ссылки";
} else {
    echo "Есть ссылка";
}
```